# dotnet command for publish in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have set up the jenkins to build and publish the .net application.
Build is successfully.
Can anyone please help , I am getting the error that dotnet is not an external or internal command.
Any suggestion on the syntax to create the package of dotnet application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can publish by command line

echo '*** publish Back End ***'
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish "%WORKSPACE%/BackEnd/BackEnd/BackEnd.csproj" --configuration Release --output "%WORKSPACE%/publish/playground2/BackEnd"